# Implement onClickListener on fragment inside FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Good day,

I have `ViewPager`, and this is adapter:

```
public abstract class GalleryImageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<? extends UrlItem> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public GalleryImageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<? extends UrlItem> images) {
        super(fm);
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return giveFragment(images, position);
    }

    public abstract Fragment giveFragment(List<? extends UrlItem> images, int position);

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(collection, position);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

I have a `ViewPager`, which represents gallery of images. I would like to handle click on current selected child (fragment) in `ViewPager`.

I found something about `instantiateItem`, but nothing about how to handle clicks in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I got the fragment in this method but `.setOnClickListener` is not found

Comment: `setOnClickListener` is only used with views! how you would it to be used on a `Fragment`. Also if you want to implement `gallery of images` why are you using an `PagerAdapter` why don't you use a `RecyclerView`!

Comment: Do you have a custom `Fragment` ? If yes, show us please.

Comment: The fragment has a layout, you can select any view in there (maybe the root view) and handle `setOnClickListener`

Answer (score -1):

If it's not needed for your image gallery items to have their own lifecycles (and I would imagine it's not), don't use Fragments and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Use a RecyclerView with the appropriate adapter, as explained, for example, [here](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/).